# Android studio FileNotFoundException for R.java

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, r.java-file

I'm getting following exception while running project.

```
Execution failed for task ':app:*****'.
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\*****\R.java (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

Tried following ways but its not working
1. Clean Project
2. Rebuild project
3. Invalidate cache and restart
4. Deleted scripts folder from .gradle/cache and rebuild

Comment: can you post your import statement for R file

Comment: @Ezio in import R is not throwing error. I get error after running

Comment: Try and delete the bin and gen folders and then rebuild the project.